# How to exclude nodes from Geometry nodes calculation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes, procedural

I'm working on a geometry node setup which will allow me to cycle through objects/collections (+I'm gonna add additional parameters to make a scene creation faster).
[image]
Objects on the screenshot represent project collections due to NDA
[image]
But these models are texture/geometry heavy and it seems that even if the switch/collection is off/false blender still calculates all the nodes that are switched off in the render

Here's the comparison: if I render 2 out of 7 collections blender uses 12gb of ram but with geometry nodes it uses 19.5gb which is like rendering all 7 of them.
[image]
Picture Above: 7 collections rendered as objects + 7 collections rendered with this node setup (7 objects as collections with corresponding switches ON)
[image]
Picture Above: 2 collections rendered with basic meshes/objects + 2 collections rendered with this node setup (2 objects use it with corresponding switches ON)

Is it possible to exclude nodes from calculation when they are not used but keeping all of these collections in one setup to have an ability to cycle through them? Otherwise I will have to split this setup into 7 different GeoNodes without an ability to switch between them on the go (it will also make it harder to migrate this setup between different blend files). I know that I can just change the node setup in the modifiers tab but it will make it more complicated to modify the whole setup and inputs for additional settings will reset to their default values.

This Geometry Node setup works blazingly fast in solid mode until material preview or render is turned on.

Comment: I understand about the NDA but posting a small example version of the blend file to https://blend-exchange.com/ and posting the created link back the question will help. You may get more help since people won't have to re-create an entire blend file.